# How to bind again after unbinding a functiion in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to bind a button to a different function after the user selects some number of points on the image with another function. Currently, I am doing like this-

```
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", func1)
canvas.unbind("<Button-1>")
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", func2)
```

This does not solve my problem as only func2 is executing. I have also tried adding the unbind statement to func1 and func2 (which runs after some condition is satisfied) but same thing is happening. Is there a way to make this run sequentially so that I can bind with func1 -> unbind func1 -> bind with func2 -> unbind func2.

I want to do the point selection in one image only without putting the image again on canvas. Also, is there any better way to approach this?

Comment: _"This is failing as both func1 and func2 are running together."_ - that is an incorrect assessment. Only the second binding will be active. Please provide a complete [mcve] that illustrates what you think is happening.

Comment: sorry I mistyped. Only func2 is executing, I have updated the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your description is unclear. If you bind to func1 and then later to func2, only func2 will run whether you call unbind or not. I can't tell if that's what you want, or if that's what you don't want.

Comment: I will provide an example soon. I want to first run func1 (bind to Button 1), then after user selects 2 points, I unbind from func1 and bind with func2 (Button 1). I want to run both functions one after the other.

Comment: See, while python runs the code first it binds to func1, then it unbinds, then it binds again to func2, all this happen together, so only the last binding takes effect, you need to have some sort of event to trigger these binding and unbinding

Comment: Yeah, how to put that trigger? In case my after the user clicks the mouse button two times, then I should exit from func1 and start using func2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example, where once you click twice on the root window, then `func2` will be used.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

count = 0
def func1(event):
    global count
    count += 1
    print('FUNC1')
    
    if count == 2:
        root.unbind('<Button-1>')
        root.bind('<Button-1>',func2)
        count = 0

def func2(event):
    print('FUNC2') #you can create similar logic to switch back to func1 here too 

root.bind('<Button-1>',func1)

root.mainloop()
```

Using a counter is a easy way to do this, not sure if this is what your looking for, but you can get an idea from here.